# How to get "Open with Google Docs" option in mobile browser

Tags: ios, safari, google-docs

i need to share some Google Docs i created with some people who have a variety of devices they use. i'd like to send them a link to the shared documents. problem is, at least on iPhone & iPad (i don't have any android devices to test with), when they click the link in an email, it launches Safari. i AM getting the popup to get the Google Docs app. but after i download it & sign in, i can't find a way to get the shared document to open in the Google Docs app!

now, on my iPhone, i do get the bar at the top that comes down with an "Open in app" button. but nothing like that on the iPad. and i have no idea about android.

also of note: i did create some Firebase Dynamic short links for these docs. i thought perhaps those would do the work of getting the user to open the documents in the app from the browser, but i don't think that's making any difference.

so, is there anything i can do to make this EASILY happen for people who aren't very technically  minded?

are there some steps/instructions on how to get a gDocs link in Safari to open in the gDocs app???

i've looked thru the "Shared" options but gDocs is not an option there.
and you can't copy/paste the link directly into the gDocs app (as far as i can find).

thanks for any help/insight.

---

UPDATE: i guess these things are called "Smart App Banners". the oddest thing is now it IS showing up on both my iphone & ipad, but it's still NOT showing up on my wife's iphone. i've rummaged thru all the settings i could find & they all match mine. so i'm confused why it seems to be selectively showing up.

without that banner, i don't know how people will get the doc into the Google Docs app from mobile Safari.

Comment: i thought "Ask Different" was for Apple products only. i'd like to not only know about that but also Android.